# Disposable Context Object pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, idisposable

## Introduction

I just thought of a new design pattern. I'm wondering if it exists, and if not, why not (or why I shouldn't use it).

I'm creating a game using an OpenGL. In OpenGL, you often want to "bind" things -- i.e., make them the current context for a little while, and then unbind them. For example, you might call `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)` then you draw some triangles, then call `glEnd()`. I like to indent all the stuff inbetween so it's clear where it starts and ends, but then my IDE likes to unindent them because there are no braces. Then I thought we could do something clever! It basically works like this:

```
using(GL.Begin(GL_BeginMode.Triangles)) {
   // draw stuff
}
```

`GL.Begin` returns a special `DrawBind` object (with an internal constructor) and implements `IDisposable` so that it automatically calls `GL.End()` at the end of the block. This way everything stays nicely aligned, and you can't forget to call end().

Is there a name for this pattern?

Usually when I see `using` used, you use it like this:

```
using(var x = new Whatever()) {
   // do stuff with `x`
}
```

But in this case, we don't need to call any methods on our 'used' object, so we don't need to assign it to anything and it serves no purpose other than to call the corresponding end function.

---

## Example

For [Anthony Pegram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414076/anthony-pegram), who wanted a real example of code I'm currently working on:

**Before refactoring:**

```
public void Render()
{
    _vao.Bind();
    _ibo.Bind(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);
    GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, _indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);
    BufferObject.Unbind(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);
    VertexArrayObject.Unbind();
}
```

**After refactoring:**

```
public void Render()
{
    using(_vao.Bind())
    using(_ibo.Bind(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer))
    {
        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, _indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Notice that there's a 2nd benefit that the object returned by `_ibo.Bind` also remembers which "BufferTarget" I want to unbind. It also draws your atention to `GL.DrawElements`, which is really the only significant statement in that function (that does something noticeable), and hides away those lengthy unbind statements.

I guess the one downside is that I can't interlace Buffer Targets with this method. I'm not sure when I would ever want to, but I would have to keep a reference to bind object and call Dispose manually, or call the end function manually.

---

## Naming

If no one objects, I'm dubbing this **Disposable Context Object (DCO) Idiom**.

---

## Problems

[JasonTrue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13433/jasontrue) raised a good point, that in this scenario (OpenGL buffers) nested using statements would not work as expected, as only one buffer can be bound at a time. We can remedy this, however, by expanding on "bind object" to use stacks:

```
public class BufferContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BufferTarget _target;
    private static readonly Dictionary<BufferTarget, Stack<int>> _handles;

    static BufferContext()
    {
        _handles = new Dictionary<BufferTarget, Stack<int>>();
    }

    internal BufferContext(BufferTarget target, int handle)
    {
        _target = target;
        if (!_handles.ContainsKey(target)) _handles[target] = new Stack<int>();
        _handles[target].Push(handle);
        GL.BindBuffer(target, handle);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _handles[_target].Pop();
        int handle = _handles[_target].Count > 0 ? _handles[_target].Peek() : 0;
        GL.BindBuffer(_target, handle);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Just noticed a problem with this. Before if you didn't `Dispose()` of your context object there wasn't really any consequence. The context just wouldn't switch back to whatever it was. Now if you forget to Dispose of it inside some kind of loop, you're wind up with a *stackoverflow*. Perhaps I should limit the stack size...

Comment: Abuse of `IDisposable` pattern? ;) - But more seriously the biggest problem with this is if someone forgets to have this in a `using` statement.

Comment: @Oded: How so? Then they just have to call the end() function manually. Isn't that the exact same issue every IDisposable object has? It's not that as though they *can't* assign the `DrawBind` object to a variable either. They can do that and then forgo the `using`.

Comment: It depends on the resource and usage scenarios. But yes, this is a potential problem with all `IDisposable`s.

Comment: The "clever" thing you should do is all that stuff you want indented so you can keep track of where it begins and ends, refactor into a method. Then you just have begin, method(), end.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Eh? Why's that better? You're basically just collapsing the stuff between begin() and end() down to one statement so that it's easier to see where it begins and ends, but that one line still isn't indented. And regardless, if I'm going to throw everything into a method, why don't I throw the begin() and end() in there too so that I don't forget to call either of them? But then we're back to square 1 again. We have a bunch of stuff between a begin and end, it's just in a different location now.

Comment: You certainly might have begin and end in a method. And the stuff in between refactored into another method. And that method might need to be refactored into still smaller methods. The issue as you expressed it is that you have a difficulty seeing where things begin and end. Says to me that your code is in need of refactoring, if that's the case. But you haven't shown your code, so I cannot say with certainty.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I haven't shown any code because I'm speaking in general. All my methods are under about 20 lines. But even so, why would I want to do it the old fashioned way (explicitly call begin() and end()) if there's a better, more clear solution? You haven't given any counter-arguments yet. Is it a performance issue perhaps?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: See my update if you want a real example. I think the refactored example is a lot more clear. It hides away those lengthy closing statements that don't really "do" anything significant so they aren't a distraction when you're reading the code.

Comment: If indenting is the goal, then try using braces alone. Otherwise it is, as @Oded said, abuse of IDisposible - not to mention a dis-service to the next person who reads that code. To wit: "why in the Wide World of Sports is there a 'using' that doesn't use?

Comment: We do similar tricks at work with transactions and connections. It's a useful pattern, but I'd only use it where I wanted the guarantee of an effective try..finally block.

Comment: OK, your original code isn't particularly lengthy, and I do not know anything about the libraries involved so I cannot offer much commentary there. I would say that I might prefer to encapsulate the binding/unbinding or begin/end in a way other than trying to use a language construct intended for something different. For example, a method that can bind, invoke a delgate/Func/Action, and then unbind. That may or not fit what you're doing, obviously.

Comment: @radarbob: If it were my only goal, I could use lone braces I suppose. I still think it has other advantages though. I'm still not understadning how it's an abuse of IDisposable or a disservice to the next person. If you read that code, what would you *think* the closing brace at the opposite end of a Begin() or Bind() then? Even without looking it up, I would guess it would End() or Unbind(). How is that unclear? Also, how is this a "'using' that doesn't use"? It is using something... you can think of it as an anonymous object that doesn't get used until the end ;)

Comment: Your stack workaround appears not to be thread-safe, though it's generally understood by most developers that having multiple threads drawing (or doing UI stuff) is a Bad Idea (tm). (The ThreadStatic attribute might do the trick, though). I'd also worry if someone might be tempted to access another context that's in scope, but not the active context.

Comment: @JasonTrue: Yeah...you definitely wouldn't want to multi-thread the render loop. The rendering already runs in its own thread, nothing else needs to touch it :) I did make one more update to it to limit the stack size to 32 (then it drops off the old values) so that if you aren't disposing it, nothing too bad will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar tactic is used with Asp.Net MVC with the HtmlHelper. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx (`using (Html.BeginForm()) {....}`)

So there's at least one precedent for using this pattern for something other than the obvious "need" for IDisposable for unmanaged resources like file handles, database or network connections, fonts, and so on. I don't think there's a special name for it, but in practice, it seems to be the C# idiom that serves as the counterpart to the C++ idiom, Resource Acquisition is Initialization.

When you're opening a file, you're acquiring, and guaranteeing the disposal of, a file context; in your example, the resource you're acquiring is a is a "binding context", in your words. While I've heard "Dispose pattern" or "Using pattern" used to describe the broad category, essentially "deterministic cleanup" is what you're talking about; you're controlling the lifetime the object.

I don't think it's really a "new" pattern, and the only reason it stands out in your use case is that apparently the OpenGL implementation you're depending on didn't make a special effort to match C# idioms, which requires you to build your own proxy object.

The only thing I'd worry about is if there are any non-obvious side effects, if, for example, you had a nested context where there were similar `using` constructs deeper in your block (or call stack).

Comment: Excellent answer, and you raise a good point at the end. In OpenGL, only one buffer can be bound at a time, so nesting them isn't actually possible. I reckon I could use some static variables to keep track of this and raise an exception if I really wanted though. Actually, better yet, I could make a stack and rebind the previous object.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET/MVC uses this (optional) pattern to render the beginning and ending of a `<form>` element like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>...</div>
}
```

This is similar to your example in that you are not consuming the value of your `IDisposable` other than for its disposable semantics.  I've never heard of a name for this, but I've used this sort of thing before in other similar scenarios, and never considered it as anything other than understanding how to generally leverage the `using` block with `IDisposable` similar to how we can tap into the `foreach` semanatics by implementing `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Aha! Good example. I would say this follows the same pattern. Bummer! I can't coin it now :p Or maybe I can still coin the name, but not claim to be its inventor.

Answer (score 1):

I would this is more an idiom than a pattern. Patterns usually are more complex involving several moving parts, and idioms are just clever ways to do things in code.

In C++ it is used quite a lot. Whenever you want to aquire something or enter a scope you create an automatic variable (i.e. on the stack) of a class that *begins* or *creates* or whatever you need to be done on entry. When you leave the scope where the automatic variable is declared the destructor is called. The destructor should then *end* or *delete* or whatever is required to clean up.

```
class Lock {
private:

  CriticalSection* criticalSection;

public:

  Lock() {
    criticalSection = new CriticalSection();
    criticalSection.Enter();
  }

  ~Lock() {
    criticalSection.Leave();
    delete criticalSection;
  }

}

void F() {
  Lock lock();

  // Everything in here is executed in a critical section and it is exception safe.
}
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work in other languages, as I figured it depended on the "using" operator, which is why I tagged it as C#. But I guess C++ has deterministic destructors, so this can work. Nice!